# Changing login url

Tags: hooks, login, logout

I've been following this guide on how to change your login url : https://www.malcare.com/blog/change-wordpress-login-url/

However, upon adding the logout, login and lost password hooks, I've noticed that I cannot log out anymore. Whenever I log out, it just redirects me to /wp-admin without logging me out.

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the article's logout hook is wrong on two or three counts:

- it needs ?action=logout, similar to the lost password link
- it needs a generated nonce too
- it doesn't respect the $redirect argument.

Here's a new version based on [the current wp_logout_url() code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.1.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L408):

```php
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'my_logout_page', 10, 2 );
function my_logout_page( $logout_url, $redirect ) {
    $args = array();
    if ( ! empty( $redirect ) ) {
        $args['redirect_to'] = urlencode( $redirect );
    }

    $logout_url = add_query_arg( $args, site_url( 'my-secret-login.php?action=logout', 'login' ) );
    $logout_url = wp_nonce_url( $logout_url, 'log-out' );

    return $logout_url;
}
```